# Remove "Watch again on YouTube" from youtube shorts played using react-native-webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview to play youtube videos on my react native app.

I wanted a feature where user wont be able to open youtube app or any thing else while watching video on my app. I am able to hide logo, share button, overflow menu and few other stuffs too.

But at the end of video a button popups called "Watch again on YouTube". I am able to hide it when normal youtube video is being played, but it still showing up when watching youtube shorts.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const YouTubePlayer = ({ videoId }) => {
  const embedUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?rel=0&modestbranding=1`;
  const injectedJavaScript = `
     const hideElements = () => {

       const logo = document.querySelector('.ytp-watermark');
       if (logo) {
         logo.style.display = 'none';
       }

       const shareButton = document.querySelector('.ytp-share-button');
       if (shareButton) {
         shareButton.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };

     const disableScrolling = () => {
       document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
     };

     const hideOverflowMenu = () => {
       const overflowMenu = document.querySelector('.ytp-overflow-menu');
       if (overflowMenu) {
         overflowMenu.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };

     const hideWatchAgain = () => {
       const watchAgain = document.querySelector('.ytp-endscreen-content');
       if (watchAgain) {
         watchAgain.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };

     const hideFullscreenButton = () => {
       const fullscreenButton = document.querySelector('.ytp-fullscreen-button');
       if (fullscreenButton) {
         fullscreenButton.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };

     const hideWatchAgainReels = () => {
       const watchAgain = document.querySelector('.ytp-reel-endscreen-content');
       if (watchAgain) {
         watchAgain.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };
     const ariaLabelHide = () => {
       const watchAgain = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Watch again on YouTube"]');
       if (watchAgain) {
         watchAgain.style.display = 'none';
       }
     };

     hideElements();
     disableScrolling();
     hideOverflowMenu();
     hideWatchAgain();
     hideFullscreenButton();
     hideWatchAgainReels();
     ariaLabelHide();

     window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, { passive: false });

     function handleTouchMove(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
     }
   `;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: embedUrl }}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      injectedJavaScript={injectedJavaScript}
    />
  );
};
export default YouTubePlayer;
```

I want to hide "Watch again on YouTube" button youtube shorts is played.